# Max dimension of an irreducible representation of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $D_n$ be the diahedral group by the notation $|D_n|= 2n$ and n be **odd**.

Then I've showed that the number of conjugate classes of $D_n$ are $\frac{n+3}{2}$.

Since the number of conjugate classes coincides with the number of irreducible representations, we have $\frac{n+3}{2}.$ However, from the notes we assume (Why?) that there can only be 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional representations. So if $a$ denotes the number of 1-dimensional repr. and $b$ the number 2-dimensional repr, and with dimensionality Theorem we get the following system:

$$a+b = \frac{n+3}{2} $$
$$ a + 4b = 2n $$

My question is, how can we conclude in this case that there can only be 1 and 2 dimensional representations?

Comment: No idea if there is a simpler way, but https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups shows how to construct $(n-1)/2$ two-dimensional representations (with distinct characters), it is obvious that they are non-abelian so they must all be irreducible.